# Make identity field as primary key or composite key of four columns

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2016

I am designing the database of a new system in which we have around 5 main tables namely ClientDwg, DwgMaster, ChildDwg, DwgMaterial, DwgComponent. All these tables have same 4 keys in common (also primary key to some extent) which are DwgNo, DwgType, DwgPart, DwgVersion.

Now my question is that should I have a composite primary key of the above four columns in each of the tables or i should have a identity field (id) as the primary key? What will be the ups and downs of both? My reall worry is that if I make above composite primary key then in my application and database I will have to reference all four fields everywhere (making joins, fetching/updating data etc.).

**Edit:** We are basically writing new application from scratch for an existing legacy application which used the composite key idea (application was vb6 and oracle db). It was too much headache in that environment. Now we are re writing the application in ASP.Net MVC 5 and SQL Server 2016.

Comment: have tried something?

Answer (score 1):

I would (almost) always vote for a single surrogate key - it's just that much simpler if you need to join that table to others.

If you have a compound key, **all** tables referencing your table must **also** have **all those columns** to establish the FK connection. And every time you write a JOIN query, you have to specify **all those columns**.

This gets **really tiring** and annoying very quickly, if you have more than two columns in your compound index......

Comment: Amen, I so agree - surrogate key is the way to go!

Comment: Totally. Pretty much the only reasonable use of a composite key is in join table, where your key is the combination of the two foreign keys. Other than that, avoid them like the plague.